# PHPUnit marking test as risky when defining expectations on passed mock

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to set test expectations on a mock object that is created in a data provider and passed to my test method. This is useful because I can reused my data provider across different test cases and have the tests define what to expect on the mock. However, phpunit marks this test as risky when the case passes, but correctly fails the test when it does not pass. Is this a known thing that cannot be done?

I am using phpunit v9.3

Here is a contrived example to show the problem:

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class Test extends TestCase
{
    public function provideMock(): array
    {
        return [
            [$this->createMock(\DateTime::class)],
        ];
    }

    /** @dataProvider provideMock */
    public function testMockPasses(MockObject $mock): void
    {
        $mock->expects($this->once())->method('format')->with('Y-m-d');
        $mock->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    /** @dataProvider provideMock */
    public function testMockFails(MockObject $mock): void
    {
        $mock->expects($this->once())->method('format')->with('Y-m-d');
        $mock->format('Y-m-');
    }
}
```

I would expect this to work fine as I am just passing the object to the method - all internal php stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running PHPUnit with `--verbose` key - it may tell more about the reason of marking the test as risky.

Comment: I run with `-v` and it tells me that there were no assertions for the risky test

Comment: That's probably because `createMock()` is not intended to get called outside of test body, because internal mock implementation is tightly bound with test lifecycle. You need to call `createMock()` at the start of each test. If you need to run same test on using different classes mocked - you still can pass class names via data provider.

Comment: Okay interesting. I will try refactoring according to your suggestion. Thanks